# HTML CSS Only border <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I want to have only one cell with a border (B2). I don't want to use a table inside a table.

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>  <!-- Only this cell should have a border -->
        <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline or apply a CSS style to that element, like so...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">B2</td>  <!-- Only this cell should have a border -->
        <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zg9d/)

Comment: When i have 2 td with a border, between the border there is a little space. i tried border-spacing:0px; but that didnt work. How can put the two borders next to eachother that the border is continious?

Comment: Add this to the top of your table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0". Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MF5Vt/).

Or, to support those browsers that don't implement `:nth-child()`:

```
tr:first-child + tr td:first-child + td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MF5Vt/1/).

Comment: Yes, that is the solution, I had use <td border="1">B2</td> but that didnt work. But this is the right solution!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n73t/)

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td class='border-me'>B2</td>  <!-- Only this cell should have a border -->
        <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.border-me{
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Yours is still valid @PeteSimmons! You had inline styles, I did not!

Comment: Plus you got a +1 and I did not :( @PeteSimmons

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<td id="bordered">B2</td>
```

CSS:

```
#bordered {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Try that.

Comment: Yup just noticed that, then fixed it